# How can I turn off extra mail sent to administrator?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, email, osx-lion, osx-server, mail-server

I have a server-config Mac mini set up at home.  When I had Snow Leopard on it, I had started setting up a mail server, but left it in a half-configured state of some kind.  I've since upgraded to Lion.  The mail server seems to be working fine; that is, I can send and receive mail, but my admin account is getting a copy of every message received by the mail server.  I do remember checking a box in Snow Leopard server admin that seemed to be intended to set up this behaviour.  Now that the server is running though, I'd like to disable it.  How can I turn off this behaviour in Lion Server?  The check box to handle it isn't in the Lion server admin app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give you two choices:

First, you can edit the file /etc/postfix/main.cf, and delete the line that starts "always_bcc=".  You'll need root access to edit it; if you're comfortable using a command-line editor like vi or nano, you can just use that with `sudo`.  If you're not comfortable with that, I recommend using [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/download.html) -- it can use your admin credentials to edit root-only files in the GUI.

Second, you can install the Server Admin Tools ([10.7.2 version is here](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1457)).  It includes Server Admin, which includes advanced mail server settings, like enabling/disabling the always_bcc option.

Comment: Gotem.  Thanks.  I was actually snooping in mail.cf when this answer showed up. I'll go check out Server Admin Tools.